# How do find the sum of an ascii array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, ascii

I'm new to java (2 weeks) and I'm trying to convert a inputted string in to ascii code and trying to print the sum.

I've tried using IntStream.of(AsciiArray).sum but since its a string and not an int it doesn't work (Understandably)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Strings{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a 5 letter word (all lower case): ");
        String word = input.nextLine(); 
        int length = word.length();
        byte[] bytes = word.getBytes(); 
        String AsciiArray = Arrays.toString(bytes);

        System.out.println("the ascii sum is" + AsciiArray);
    }

}
```

example of what I'm trying to do: 
"Enter a 5 letter word (all lower case): "

hello

the ascii sum is 532

what I get:

"Enter a 5 letter word (all lower case): "

hello

the ascii sum is [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sums-of-ascii-values-of-each-word-in-a-sentence/

Comment: You forget to sum up the `bytes`.

Comment: Sure the input is assumed to be characters from the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block, but please use a [getBytes method overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-) who's result doesn't vary based on a system' s user's current settings. `getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`. The "default" charset is never what you should use except when it is exactly what you need (which is rare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already get every ASCII value of the input word, but forget to sum them up.

For example:

```
byte[] bytes = word.getBytes(); 
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sum += bytes[i];
}
System.out.println("the ascii sum is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 7):

A more simpler solution to find the sum of all characters :

```
System.out.println("the ascii sum is " + word.chars().sum());
```

Comment: This, of course, is the sum of the UTF-16 code units, which makes more sense in Java since Java's text datatypes don't use ASCII.