# How do I find the word with the highest sum of ASCII value from an array of Strings?

Tags: java

I have the following code which is my attempt:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = "The quick brown fox";
        System.out.println(highestRanking(sample));
    }


    public static String highestRanking(String sentence){

        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        String highestWord = "";
        int biggestASCIIValue = 0;
        for (String word : words){
            if (word.chars().sum() > biggestASCIIValue){
                highestWord = word;
            }
        }
        return highestWord;
    }
```

For some reason the sum of word chars is giving me zero. I found this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730432/how-do-find-the-sum-of-an-ascii-array).
Any ideas why my code doesn't seem to work?
Thank you

Comment: You need to update `biggestASCIIValue = word.chars().sum();`

Comment: *For some reason the sum of word chars is giving me zero.* Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream API offers [`Stream::max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) accepting a custom `Comparator`:

```java
public static String highestRanking(String sentence){
    return Arrays.stream(sentence.split("\\s+"))
        .max(Comparator.comparingInt(word -> word.chars().sum()))
        .orElse(null);
}
```